# How does one test AuthController generated by Shiro Grails plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, shiro

I'm getting very frustrated with the Shiro plugin for Grails. First, I'm trying to set up an ini-based SecurityManager like the beginner tutorial for Shiro suggests, and there's nothing in the documentation that tells me how things get configured. So, after struggling to figure it out, and ultimately failing, I just concede that I have to go with the `DbRealm` that was generated with the quickstart command. Now I'm trying to discover how things are working by creating a unit test for the generated `AuthController`. Here's my test code:

```
void "registered user logs in with valid credentials"() {
    given: "user 'root' is registered"
    def username = "root"
    def password = "secret"
    new User(username: username, password: password).save();

    when: "user logs in with correct credentials"
    params.username = username
    params.password = password
    controller.signIn();

    then: "user should be authenticated"
    assertTrue SecurityUtils.subject.authenticated
}
```

I'm still not sure how to verify the user is actually logged in so I thought the code in the `then` block should be fine for now. However, every time I try testing the app with `grails test-app`, I always get:

```
org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.
    at org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSecurityManager(SecurityUtils.java:123)
```

I'm not exactly new to Grails but it's been a very long time since I last used it, and I never really had that that much exposure to the framework, anyway. However, I know it's supposed to make things less complicated to set up, but the Shiro plugin is giving me a difficult time.

So, how do I go about configuring my app, and/or testing the generated `AuthController`?